# Capture commands of python setuptools?

Tags: python-3.x, distutils

I'm porting python to QNX. I'm trying to port some external dependencies now and cython is a part of it.

The problem is, cython installs using the distutils setup script which too abstract to understand. I spawned a virtual environment and ran the setup script with

> --verbose

flag and some of the messages printed to stdout looked like this.

```
Compiling /home/arvind/Documents/venv/env/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.py because it changed.

Cythonizing /home/arvind/Documents/venv/env/cython/Cython/Compiler/FusedNode.py
```

I find this too abstract be able to recreate on an other platform. Is there a way I could see exactly what compiling/ cythonizing is doing?

I want to capture the commands that distutils hiding from the user. Any ideas?

Comment: No magic here - `Compiling Actions.py` line means that the `Actions.py` file will be compiled to `Actions.so`. First, a file `Actions.c` will be generated from `Actions.py` ("cythonized"), then `Actions.c` is compiled to `Actions.so` as a usual extension, using the system compiler. Cythonizing can be triggered from command line via `cython Actions.py` with the same effect as in setup script.